# Can a merchant charge me on my credit card one year after transaction date?

Tags: credit-card, india

What is the time constraint put on the merchant to charge customers on their credit card?

Edit:
Country: India,
Card: Amex,
Purchases: Coffee and snacks

Comment: what type of transaction? Annual dues or a bag of chips? which network? which country?

Comment: Has this happened to you, or are you asking hypothetically?

Comment: Happened to me. They charged me for around 10 transactions spread out in six months, without giving me the exact transaction date. So I wanted to know the legality of this.

Comment: Since you are dealing with Amex, get in touch with them for details regarding the suspicious transactions. Identify the fake ones and get in touch with them for dispute.There is no time limit for cardmembers--a transaction can be disputed at any time. Amex is known for customer friendly resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you legally owe them the money (because you bought something and received it), they can try to charge your card anytime. If your card doesn't exist anymore, they can contact you and ask for other form of payment.
Your debt doesn't simply go away because they neglected or delayed for whatever reason to collect it.

Many countries do have a statute of limitations, which disallows following up on old debt after a certain period of silence (but I doubt any country has a year or less); some countries don't - this depends on your country. [Edit: I don't know for India]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I get to know about the time limit for credit card charging, in my country? What should I be searching for? I tried a few keywords, but nothing related is showing up in search results.

Comment: There wouldn't be a specific limitation for credit card charging, look for 'how long can a debt be collected' or similar.

Comment: The debt doesn't go away, but particular means of collecting it can. Whether the merchant is entitled to use Amex's as a means of collecting on a debt depends on Amex's conditions, not on whether the OP owes the debt.

Comment: There are _some_ limitations on credit-card charging, at least if the merchant originally authorised payment and then didn't process it within the approved timetable... see [Late Presentment Chargeback](https://chargebacks911.com/knowledge-base/why-did-i-get-a-late-presentment-charge/) (from a chargeback-management company's site) which goes into the limits for both Mastercard and Visa. However, it doesn't cover any limits from simply "forgetting" to initiate the whole process in a timely manner.